# Plotting using basemap and descartes doesn't show PolygonPatch

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, shapely, descartes

I can plot some Shapely buffered points like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from shapely.geometry import Point
from descartes import PolygonPatch

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = [-6.108398, 49.61071, 1.669922, 58.972667]
w, h = maxx - minx, maxy - miny
x, y = (-0.117588, 51.513230)
correct = Point(x, y).buffer(0.5)
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(correct, fc='#cc00cc', ec='#555555', alpha=0.5, zorder=5))
ax.set_xlim(minx - 0.2 * w, maxx + 0.2 * w)
ax.set_ylim(miny - 0.2 * h, maxy + 0.2 * h)
ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.add_patch(patch)
plt.show()
```

This results in the following plot:

[image]

However, if I try to plot these points using Basemap, they don't appear:

```
bounds = [-6.108398, 49.61071, 1.669922, 58.972667]
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = bounds
w, h = maxx - minx, maxy - miny
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
m = Basemap(
    projection='merc',
    ellps = 'WGS84',
    llcrnrlon=minx - 0.2 * w,
    llcrnrlat=miny - 0.2 * h,
    urcrnrlon=maxx + 0.2 * w,
    urcrnrlat=maxy + 0.2 * h,
    lat_ts=0,
    resolution='i')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawmapboundary()
# set axes limits to map crs
min_x, min_y = m(minx, miny)
max_x, max_y = m(maxx, maxy)
corr_w, corr_h = max_x - min_x, max_y - min_y
ax.set_xlim(min_x - 0.2 * corr_w, max_x + 0.2 * corr_w)
ax.set_ylim(min_y - 0.2 * corr_h, max_y + 0.2 * corr_h)
ax.set_aspect(1)
# add known good coordinate
x, y = m(-0.117588, 51.513230)
correct = Point(x, y).buffer(1.)
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(correct, fc='#cc00cc', ec='#555555', alpha=0.5, zorder=5))

plt.show()
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you provided a working example, your image cannot be reproduced with the code you supplied.

If you plot with Basemap on a Mercator projected map, the coordinates you supply should be in the same projection. You are plotting WGS84 lat/lon on a Mercator projected map, thats not going to work. The buffer you apply to the points is also expressed in the map coordinates, which is meters instead of degrees.

The map object provides easy conversion with:

```
x,y = m(lon,lat)
```

So change your point creation to:

```
Point(m(lon, lat)).buffer(1000)
```

Comment: Changing the buffer size to meters has caused the point to be visible. Thanks!